# Trying to automate tabs and shell commands in Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-mavericks, osascript

I have a custom vim setup running inside split (GNU) screen sessions running in several tabs inside Terminal. Naturally I want to automate all that. So Ive Googled a lot and most answers talk about using `osascript -e` to run a bunch of AppleScript commands. My situation is slightly different: first Im using TotalTerminal, a plugin for Terminal (dont think it matters but mention it just in case) and Im writing a hashbang script and not a bash script, i.e.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript                                                            
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
tell application "Terminal" to activate                                         
tell application "Terminal" to do script with command "cd ~/Desktop/Projects && screen -d -U -R -A"
```

which Im running from the command-line. The tab opening works but the script/command runs in a new window instead of inside a newly-created tab.

Comment: Try using Tmux it makes this a lot simplier. https://tmux.github.io/

Comment: Indeed, `tmux` plus `tmuxinator`: even better.  Also iTerm (a Terminal.app replacement) lets you have different profiles that can run certain commands upon launch. You could easily chain these, so that you tell iTerm to launch with a certain profile and that profile starts tmuxinator for you (which gives you are arrangement of screen-like sessions).

Comment: @h0lyalg0rithm  Not really - to do the equivalent of my split screen setup in tmux would require me to use several files instead of just one, for minimal gains. My question is concerned with tabs in Terminal which has nothing to do with screen anyway.

Comment: @tilthouse I pretty much use the keyboard controls for everything and prefer TotalTerminal's "drop-down-from-a-hotkey-but-stay-out-of-my-way-after-Im-done" approach. It integrate's seamlessly with Terminal instead of being a whole 'nother app. So basically, ^` to drop down; shift cmd { or shift cmd } to switch tabs; ^a to initiate screen cmd, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I might recommend setting things up:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    do script "cd ~/Desktop/Projects && screen -d -U -R -A" in window frontmost
    do script "clear; echo 'Hello, World!'" in tab 1 of window frontmost
end tell
```

**Note**: You also can select the tab you want the next command to go into by using `tab x`. If you switch back to the first tab you should notice the echo sent to it after creating the new tab.

The example above is a few more lines of code perhaps, although it should get all the processes correctly in order. I think the key ingredient is having Terminal **set frontmost to true** which gets the current Terminal window to start interacting with the rest of the script.

**EDIT**: The OP came back and needed to make a few changes and this was the end result:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal"
        set frontmost to true
    end tell
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script "mosh user@someserver" in window frontmost
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down
    do script "cd ~/Desktop/Projects && screen -d -U -R -A" in tab 2 of window frontmost
end tell
```

Comment: Yes, frontmost is key. Ive come up with this now though the first `do` is being flagged as a syntax error:
    `#!/usr/bin/osascript  
    tell application "System Events" to tell application "Finder"
      tell process "Terminal"
        set frontmost to true
      end tell
    end tell
    tell application "Terminal"  
      activate  
      do script "mosh user@someserver" in window frontmost  
      tell application "System Events" to keystroke "t" using command down  
      do script "cd ~/Desktop/Projects/ussie/mobile && screen -d -U -R -A" in tab 2 of window frontmost  
    end tell`

Comment: Yeah, I figured you might need to tweak a few things; if it works then you've probably got the gist of it  :)

Comment: telling the Finder is not needed at all, System Events is able to handle all events by itself

Comment: Im guessing the editor Im using was incorrectly flagging the first `do` as a syntax error, because everything works. I inserted `delay 6` after the `mosh` command to allow time for the remote server login before sending another `screen` command to the same window to reconnect a remote server-side screen session. I have three other local screen sessions, each one in its own tab and three other misc. tabs. Thanks very much for the assist!